# How to remove some data in Header in next page (RDLC Report)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, report, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm having a trouble on creating reports for my client because of the format. I just want to display the logo on the first page of my report and the rest will display without the logo. Please see my sample format.

[image]

Note: I dont want to remove the title on my header because I want to show that to all pages. I just want to remove or hide some data on header.

Comment: Check the "PrintOnFirstPage" property for Page Header..

Comment: I did that. Showing header on first page will remove the title ABC Company on the other pages. I have two data in Header the 'Sample Header 1' and 'ABC Company'. I dont want to show the 'Sample Header 1' in the next page.

Comment: You can change the visibility property to "=(Globals!PageNumber <> 1)"

Comment: You can put the header in Lable which needs to be visible on the other page. Make the conditional visibility of the Lable like. =iif(Fields!HeaderFlag.Value == 1,true ,false)

Comment: the result is the header size decreases and body size increases but the contents on the body goes to middle instead on the upper part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the following expression for the `Hidden` property should give you the desired behavior, like Ashnish Emmanuel suggested.

```
=(Globals!PageNumber <> 1)
```

When an item gets hidden, the objects below will move up. This means that the header's size should indeed shrink. This should then cause the body to move up as well. 
The size of the body won't really change , there will just be more space on the page for the body to use.

However, if you defined a fixed height for the header, this will not force it to shrink because it will keep the empty space behind the last item. Which will mean that your body won't move up either. If you wish to create space between controls I suggest you always do it inside a report item (ex: rectangle, textbox, tablix) because this will give you more control over it (expressions).

Another solution is to remove the report header all together and work with a `Tablix` with a single column. You can replace the `TextBoxes` in the cells with `Rectangles`. The header row has the same functionalities as the page header, but you also have a `CanGrow`and `CanShrink` property which could solve your problem. You can also define multiple header rows which would allow you to hide an entire row with ease.
For the row used as body, you should then re-size the rectangle to be the same size as the actual page. And set the `Keep Together`property as true. This will then break the same way like the regular report body.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Report Header.

In RDLC any control which is out the Table or the Tablix it will not be repeated, hence work as report header !

if you want to repeat , you place the item/data it in page header , use it for your Title.

Comment: He is using a Report Header already. He also wants the header on the second page and so on. Placing the parts he doesn't want repeated just above his table will indeed only display it once, but how can he align it correctly with the rest of the header? You clearly didn't read his question closely before posting at all..